# Show hidden textbox and label after dropdownlist selectedindex changed

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

C# code:

```
    protected void DropDownListDB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownListDB.SelectedValue == "Other")
        {
            LabelIfOtherDb.Visible = true;
            TextBoxIfOtherDb.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

ASP code:

```
                <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="DropDownListDB" runat="server" Height="20px" 
                    Width="158px">
                    <asp:ListItem>- Select -</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Oracle</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MS SQL Server</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MySQL</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MS Access</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have `AutoPostBack="True"` but still it doesn't show my hidden textbox/label.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="DropDownListDB" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListDB_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" Height="20px" 
                    Width="158px">
                    <asp:ListItem>- Select -</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Oracle</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MS SQL Server</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MySQL</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>MS Access</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```